# how can I mask date input in vuetify, v-date-picker component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add an input to permit users to typing date with the format locale dd/mm/YYYY.

**MyPage.vue**

```vuejs
<v-date-picker
  class="custom-input"
  hide-details
  v-model="date"
  ref="paDate"
  readonly
  hideDetails/>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date()
```

I tryied v-mask and vue-the-mask but both shows 01012020

Also i'd like to know if is it possible to check if date inputted is a valid date (day 1-31 / month 1-12)

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment.js for that. Example would be:

```
import moment from 'moment'

  data() {
   return {
    date: moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY")
   }
  }
```

More info about formatting options [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/)
Also date could be validated with moment.js

Comment: thanks for your reply, but from the documentation you provide:

" *In most cases, you should not choose Moment for new projects.* "

Also, It conflits with the *DatePicker* package, same results as v-mask and vue-the-mask

Comment: You can try another library for that. Check Vuetify doc 
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#formatting-with-external-libraries

Comment: dayjs is small and very similar to moment.  `dayjs.format("DD/MM/YYYY")`